# Binding through UserControl breaks when changing values in UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I have the following UserControl and Window, each with a slider which should be bound to the same Property, here defined in the window as a dependency property. When I move the slider in the main window, the slider in the UserControl follows. If I touch the slider in the UserControl, the slider in the main window won't change and the binding breaks, as the slider in the UserControl won't follow the one in the main window anymore. The slider in the main window doesn't loose it's binding. What am I doing wrong?

**The Window**

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(float), typeof(Window1),
                                    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata());

    public float Value {
        get { return (float)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
    }
}

<Window
    x:Class="UserControlBindingDemo.Window1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:user="clr-namespace:UserControlBindingDemo"
    Title="UserControlBindingDemo"
    Height="300"
    Width="300"
    x:Name="wndw">
    <Grid>
        <Slider
            Grid.Column="0"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Value="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=wndw}" />
        <user:UserControl1
            Grid.Column="0"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Value="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=wndw}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**The UserControl**

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(float), typeof(UserControl1),
                                    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata());

    public float Value {
        get { return (float)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
    }
}

<UserControl x:Class="UserControlBindingDemo.UserControl1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Name="uc">
    <Grid>
        <Slider
            Value="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=uc}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DependencyProperty` you have created in the `UserControl` does not update the source of the binding by default.

So when you change `Value` via the `UserControls` slider, the binding will not automatically change `Value` in the `Window`.

To fix it you can set the [Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.mode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of the `Binding` to `TwoWay`.

This will make sure that changes to the binding-target (`Value` in `UserControl`) will update the binding-source (`Value` in `Window`)

```
<user:UserControl1
    Grid.Column="0"
    Grid.Row="1"
    Value="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=wndw, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Comment: Thank you, that made it clear. I also found the way to get the `DependencyProperty` make `TwoWay` `Binding`s by default. For that I wrote a private static method returning an instance of `FrameworkPropertyMetadata` with the `BindsTwoWayByDefault` option set to `true` that I use in the `Register` call.